# Cannot set a text view as Title on a custom dialog with setTitle method

Tags: android, android-studio, customdialog

I have created a custom dialog with

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(loginPage.this);
```

Then I have created a text view to use it as title for this dialog:

```
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setText("Custom Centered Title");
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

But for some reason this line throws an error even though Dialog class has a method as setTitle(@StringRes int titleId).

```
dialog.setTitle(title.getId());
```

Am I missing something?? :/

Update:

Found out the reason for error. 
But still cannot set the text view as title on the dialog. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think is your annotation `@StringRes` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringRes.

Comment: Got it! It is supposed to a String resource not a view resource.

Comment: Still. How can I set the Text view as title on this custom dialog?

Answer (score 1):

`dialog.setTitle(title.getId());` just gets the text from your strings resources and set's it to the dialog title and your should use String res id or String !

if you want to use custom view in your dialog follow this steps :

1- create your dialog layout inside layout folder  some thing like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

2- create your dialog and disable default titleBar :

```
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

3- set your layout id to the dialog and obtain your views from the layout then your can initialize them  :

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);

TextView title = dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);

TextView message = dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);

title.setText("Hello");

message.setText("Good luck");
```

and finally your dialog looks like this :

[image]